# Web e API no Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

Alguém poderia explicar sobre as mudanças de rotas na versão 5.6 do Laravel, agora tem os arquivos web.php e api.php, e quais middleware o api está usando.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, o arquivo `api.php` está presente desde a versão `5.3` do Laravel.

A diferença basica é que o arquivo `api.php` é onde você vai colocar as rotas de sua api, caso sua aplicação seja baseada em uma api rest.

Todas as rotas nesse arquivo vão ter por padrão o prefixo `/api`, então se vc definir uma rota `/login` dentro do arquivo, o prefixo será adicionado e a rota final será `/api/login`.

Se você for fazer uma aplicação web normal, seguindo o padrão MVC, por convenção você vai definir suas rotas no `web.php`.

Claro que você pode também usar os dois ao mesmo tempo, caso necessário :)

[Aqui estão os release notes do Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/releases#laravel-5.3).